# Prolog program to find odd values from a tree that repeat twice in another tree

Tags: list, tree, prolog, binary-tree

This is a midterm exam that a professor provided to us to study. The text is like this:
Write a Prolog program twiceTinT1(T,T1),
which takes in input two binary trees T, T1, and is true if and only if each odd
value in the tree T appears twice in the tree T1.
For instance:

twiceTinT1( t(-1,t(3,nil,t(2,nil,t(3,nil,nil)))),
t(-1,t(7,nil,nil),t(3,nil,t(-1,nil,t(3,nil,nil)))))
is true.

My code is as it follows:

```
even(X):-0 is X mod 2.
odd(X):-1 is X mod 2.

%%List containing the odd numbers of a list

listodd(X,LR):-even(X).
listodd(X,[X|LR]):-odd(X).
listodd([X|L],[X|LR]):-odd(X),listodd(L,LR).
listodd([X|L],LR):-even(X),listodd(L,LR).

%Counts the occurrences of a number if a list

occurrences(X,[],0).
occurrences(X,[X|L],Res):-occurrences(X,L,Oldres),Res is Oldres+1.
occurrences(X,[Y|L],Res):-X\==Y,occurrences(X,L,Res).

%%Counts if a number occurs N times in a list

noccurrences(N,[],[]).
noccurrences(N,[X|L],[X|LR]):-occurrences(X,[X|L],N),
    noccurrences(N,L,LR).
noccurrences(N,[X|L],LR):-occurrences(X,[X|L],A),A\==N,
    noccurrences(N,L,LR).

%%Finds a value in a list

find(Y,[Y|_]).
find(Y,[X|L]):- find(Y,L).

%%%This function returns a list with the nodes of the tree

leaves(nil,[]).
leaves(t(Root,Left,Right),[Root|Res]):- leaves(Left,Lres),
            leaves(Right,Rres), append(Lres,Rres,Res).

listinlist([],L2).
listinlist(X,L2):-find(X,L2).
listinlist([X|L1],L2):-find(X,L2),listinlist(L1,L2).



twice(T1,T2):-leaves(T1,L1),leaves(T2,L2),listodd(L1,O1),
    noccurrences(2,T2,R2),listinlist(O1,R2).
```

I've tested the functions one by one with the trees t(1,nil,nil) and t(1,t(1,nil,nil),nil) and they work fine, but when I execute the main function, it returns false.

PD: I'm not trying to cheat on an exam, in case anyone thinks that. The exam is this week so every help I get is welcomed.

Comment: `t(-1,t(3,nil,t(2,nil,t(3,nil,nil))))` is not a binary tree.

Comment: Oh yeah, this professor is not known to check wheter what he writes is correct, but the purpose of the program still stands. I cannot make it work to simple trees with just 2 nodes.

Comment: Try using `trace` and see which predicate is failing. for example in a simple execution your `listodd([-1, 3, 2, 3], X)` is throwing an exception. When a complicated setup is failing, try out each part of it with examples.